# require sudo password for specific commands

Tags: linux, debian, password, sudo

I'm trying to force a password on specific commands with sudo everytime of execution regardless if the password has been entered a second ago. 
Is there a way of doing that?

Every search result on google just explains on how to remove the password prompt with NOPASSWD which is ok but I still want SPECIFIC commands to get a password prompt every time they get executed even if the password was just entered a second ago.

My approach was this:

```
Defaults               !authenticate
Cmnd_Alias             WITHPW = rm -R, shutdown,
Defaults:WITHPW        authenticate
```

Can someone explain if thats the right way or what can I do?

Thanks,

A/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between two options:

> `authenticate`
>
> If set, users must authenticate themselves via a password
>   (or other means of authentication) before they may run commands. This
>   default may be overridden via the `PASSWD` and `NOPASSWD` tags. This flag
>   is *on* by default.
>
> `passwd_timeout`
>
> Number of minutes before the sudo password prompt times
>   out, or `0` for no timeout. The timeout may include a fractional
>   component if minute granularity is insufficient, for example `2.5`. The
>   default is `5`.

While you can set both per `Cmnd_Alias`, the `passwd_timeout` is the correct option for what you are trying to achieve.

Then, let's look at the syntax for `Defaults`:

```
Default_Type ::= 'Defaults' |
                 'Defaults' '@' Host_List |
                 'Defaults' ':' User_List |
                 'Defaults' '!' Cmnd_List |
                 'Defaults' '>' Runas_List

Default_Entry ::= Default_Type Parameter_List

Parameter_List ::= Parameter |
                   Parameter ',' Parameter_List

Parameter ::= Parameter '=' Value |
              Parameter '+=' Value |
              Parameter '-=' Value |
              '!'* Parameter
```

When specifying a `Cmnd_List` or `Cmnd_Alias` you need `!` prefix, resulting:

```
Cmnd_Alias          WITHPW = /usr/bin/rm -R, /usr/sbin/shutdown
Defaults:!WITHPW    passwd_timeout=0
```

Comment: so I could use Cmnd_Alias WITHPW = /usr/bin/rm -R, /usr/sbin/shutdown Defaults:!WITHPW passwd_timeout=0 authenticate ? I want to also require a password for these commands but for all other nope. Or do I need to make a new defaults line with Defaults:!WITHPW ?

Comment: If you really have `Defaults !authenticate`, which would be careless, you need to revert that with `Defaults:!WITHPW    passwd_timeout=0, authenticate`.

Comment: I made a new file called defaults in /etc/sudoers.d/ but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't work: I still not need to enter a password which is not what I want

Comment: If you wish to use `/etc/sudoers.d`, you should have `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d`. I warmly recommend that a beginner always uses [`visudo`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/visudo.man.html) to edit `/etc/sudoers` directly – just because there's less room for errors that way.